# Role based authentication in Vue using JWT

Tags: rest, web, vue.js

I'm working on a project with a RESTful Java backend and a Vue SPA front-end. Whilst figuring out how to do user authentication I came across JWT-tokens and since it (sorta) was what I was looking for I recklessly implemented it.

Few weeks later I realize that because the content being shown on the client side, depends on the users role, the client of course needs to know the users role. For obvious reasons I don't want to store the users role inside my client.

My question: I could create a request on the server that looks at the Authentication header and returns the role, but would this be save? If not are there any common strategies when it comes to roles and JWT-tokens? Or should I forget the JWT way of doing things and implement another kind of authentication entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWT is the common way to Authenticate users with SPA as Frontend + REST Api as backend.

1. You definitely **should not** store your Token Secret in frontend app.
2. You definitely **can do** kind of `/user/roles` endpoint in your API which will return the list of user's role.

**Point 2 solution is 100% safe.** Why? Even if someone will hack your frontend app to show the content which they should not see, your backend is checking Authorization at endpoint, so they will not get/put/change any data which they have not privilege to access in their JWT.

Comment: Thank you for your Crystal clear anwser. It helps me a lot getting a general understanding.